# Getting pdf to open in full screen on edge

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pdf

I am new to working with python as I was assigned a task for something simple. I am trying to open a local pdf file to show full screen on a windows machine using microsoft edge pdf viewer. I figured you can just send a key press of f11, but that doesnt show the pdf in full screen. On Edge, there is a tool bar with the button called "Enter PDF full screen" and when that is that is pressed it shows the full pdf that F11 won't do. I was looking into this and it was suggested to use Selenium for this. I tried this code and it opens but it wont press the "Enter PDF full screen" that I had put in. I do have the the edge driver in the path and that shows its being seen.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong or how to improve it.
Thank you

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
# Set the path to the Microsoft Edge driver

pdf_file = r'C:\test.pdf'

edge_path = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe'

# Open the PDF file in Microsoft Edge using Selenium
options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
options.binary_location = edge_path
driver = webdriver.Edge(options=options)
driver.get(pdf_file)

# Wait for Microsoft Edge to load the PDF file
time.sleep(5)

# Find the "Enter PDF full screen" button and click it
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@aria-label='Enter PDF full screen']")
button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

i have just checked that function in edge. One of the things i have noticed with your code is `aria-label`

The button have id `#full-screen`, so advising to use it.
Example code:

```
fullScreenBtn = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#full-screen')
fullScreenBtn.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that using Selenium, "Enter PDF full screen" which is an Edge PDF viewer button cannot be accessed using Selenium as they are not part of the HTML DOM (Document Object Model) and are instead part of the PDF viewer itself, which is typically rendered by the browser's built-in PDF viewer.

Selenium is designed to interact with elements within the HTML DOM, so it may not be able to directly manipulate elements within the PDF viewer.

Comment: are you sure about this? So why there is an option to INPECT on the right mouse click on 'ENTER PDF FULL SIZE' button? This then opens the source code in DEV TOOLS, where you can see the DOM exists. You can see there is BUTTON with ID 'full-screen' but you cannot execute click() on it. 

Below doesn't work:

Dim result2 = Await DirectCast(sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2).CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelector('#full-screen').click();")

Answer (score 0):

The following should work OS cmd shell

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --kiosk --no-first-run --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen "file:///C:/test.pdf#toolbar=0"`

The URL includes the toolbar off flag fragment and kiosk mode runs edge with restricted controls and the full screen switch is self explanatory!

[image]

As shown you can still use your own windows toolbars to change page zoom in out or launch in other applications etc. however for Read Aloud and other user assistive functions I would leave the inlineFrames toolbar active.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to set the view of the **WebView2** PDF file to full screen (in Visual Studio) but I failed to do so. One of the approaches is to use **ExecuteScriptAsync** and execute the javascript **click**() method on button with id **full-screen**. This is done on '**NavigationCompleted**' event, so the PDF is fully loaded in **WebView2**

The below code doesn't work. Not sure why. Any recommendations?

Dim result2 = Await DirectCast(sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2).CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelector('#full-screen').click();")

[image: cannot click on it using ExecuteScriptAsync]

[image: Screenshot from Dev Tools]